# HTML2PDF 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: php, server, cpanel, tcpdf, html2pdf

I am trying to convert HTML 2 PDF with [this](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) library and its converting fine as per my expectations.

However, When I convert with more data, its giving me an error saying **504 Gateway Timeout**. Here is the error screenshot what I am getting.

[image]

In local server its working fine. I have the same server in my local and my live (Linux). The only problem is I am getting when I try to produce PDF with long data on live server.

I researched and found out that to increase php execution time and other settings. Hence I try to put below code in my **.php** file.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000);
ini_set('post_max_size','128M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','128M');
```

I even try to set `max_execution_time` to `0` and `-1` but yet its not working for me. After setting this values, I even printed the updated values with `phpinfo()`, the values are overwriting but I am having the same **502 Gateway timeout** error. Here is small chunk of code just in case you want to see.

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000);
ini_set('post_max_size','20M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','8M');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/templateInfo.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;
use technobrave\brochuresettings\Models\Brochuresettings as BS;
use Technobrave\Transactions\Models\Transactions as TR;
use Technobrave\Offices\Models\Offices;
use technobrave\themesettings\Models\ThemeSetting as TS;
use Technobrave\Team\Models\Team;



class generateTemplate {



    public $theme = "";

    public $theme_settings = array();

    public function __construct($templateId, $resolution , $theme ,$pdf_sections = array(),$openFile = false, $finalPdfFile = null) {

        $this->getBrochureTransactionData = BS::first();
        $this->getPdfSection = $pdf_sections;
        $this->theme_settings = TS::first();
        $this->theme = $theme;
        $this->baseUrl = url(Config::get('cms'));
        $this->teamPageName = $this->baseUrl . '/our-team';
        $this->capabilitiesPageName = $this->baseUrl . '/capabilities';
        $this->getFooterText = $this->getFooterText();
        $getTeamId = (isset($_GET['teamId']) && !empty($_GET['teamId'])) ? $_GET['teamId'] : "";
        $this->uniquePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $templatePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'regency_template' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $getTeamId . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $templateId . '.php';
        $templateInfoText = new templateInfo($templateId, $this->uniquePath, $getTeamId);
        $this->customImagePath = $this->uniquePath;

        foreach ($templateInfoText->defaultValues as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }


        $template = file_get_contents($templatePath);



        try 
        {

            $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('L','A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
            $html2pdf->Addfont('perpetua');
            $html2pdf->Addfont('montserratbold');
            $html2pdf->Addfont('montserratmedium');
            $html2pdf->Addfont('montserratregular');
            $html2pdf->Addfont('montserratsembold');
            $html2pdf->Addfont('montserratitalic');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($template, false);

            $html2pdf->Output('regency_corporate_brochure.pdf', 'D');


        } catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
            $formatter = new ExceptionFormater($e);
            echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to preview how my HTML is generating and its generating without any error.

```
$html2pdf->writeHTML($template, true);
```

So basically I am facing server issue here as per my understanding so far.

Can someone guide me what should I do from here on to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After a hard debugging I found that my problem was that I was including an external image in the PDF and the server can't reach the server image (server access only trough white-list IP).